# csrf_tokens do not match in flask & nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, csrf-token

Now I am trying to develop server using nginx + unicorn + flask.

If I execute python only, csrf_tokens work without any problems.

However, if I execute python using nginx + unicorn + flask, the error occurs.

**400 BAD Request - The CSRF session token is missing. or The CSRF tokens do not match.**

Is there additional settings that I should have done for nginx for session?

or Did I miss something??

app/**init**.py

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CsrfProtect

csrf = CsrfProtect()

def create_app(config_name):
   app = Flask(__name__, instance_path='/instance')
   app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
   config[config_name].init_app(app)

   bootstrap.init_app(app)
   moment.init_app(app)
   csrf.init_app(app)
   app.config.update(CSRF_ENABLED = app.config['CSRF_ENABLED'])

   //CSRF_ENABLED = True

   return app
```

login.html

```
<form action="{{url_for('.login')}}" class="form-signin text-center" method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
</form>
```

Comment: Check this [link](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/fix-missing-csrf-token-issues-with-flask)

Comment: @Tobin I've already read that link and tried it. It didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I often use in my projects the combination of flask + gunicorn + nginx. For my forms I use a different approach:

**form.py**:

```
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Optional

class IdentityForm(FlaskForm):
    age = IntegerField("Type your age", validators=[Optional()])
    name = StringField("Type your name*", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

**page.html**

```
 <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
     {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

     {{ form.age.label }}<br>
     {{ form.age() }}

     {{ form.name.label }}<br>
     {{ form.name() }}

    {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

In this small example the part that concerns us here is the argument `form.hidden_tag()` on the HTML's side. This argument generates a hidden field that includes a token that is used to protect the form against CSRF attacks. 
For this to work it is necessary to define the variable `SECRET_KEY` in the flask configurations:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'do-not-get-tired-youll-never-find'
```

The `SECRET_KEY` is a cryptographic key that makes it possible to generate signatures or tokens. `FLASK_WTF` use it to protect forms against CSRF attacks.

And that's all. `FLASK_WTF` takes care of the rest for you

To learn more take a look at [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms)